# How do I upload small exercises to GitHub?

Tags: github

So basically I am trying to learn C# and JS and I'm doing so by reading documentation and solving some small exercises.

I read somewhere that uploading most of your work to GitHub is helpful when you apply for a job so people can actually see that you've been working.

Since I am not that familiar with GitHub (I read some documentation but it confused me a bit) I wanted to know what is the best way to upload my exercises there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do some beginner course about "Git" and "Github".

It's definitely a good idea to use [GitHub desktop](https://desktop.github.com/). This tool makes it easier to manage and commit changes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a git repository for each of your projects. Put the files in there and upload them to GitHub.

Try looking at GitHub documentation like this to get started:
https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/